# How to prevent column total Count from display on component.html?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular7, angular-components

I have field total count I need to prevent total Count from display on component.html

I already do it but not working if you can tell me how to do that ?

I display data dynamically on header column and body data with angular 7

I try using filter function below but not working

```
this._displayreport.GetReportDetailsPaging(this.searchData).subscribe((data: any[]) => {

        this.reportdetailslist = data;
  this.headerCols = Object.keys(data[0]);
  this.contentBody=data.filter(item =>item != data[0].totalCount);

      });


    }


  }


<thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th >
                      <ng-container *ngIf="coln != 'totalCount'">

                        {{coln}}
                      </ng-container>
                    </th>


                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    <tr *ngFor="let rep of contentBody">

                      <td *ngFor="let coln of headerCols">


                        <span> 

                        {{rep[coln]}}
                        </span>
                       </td>
                       </tr>
                      <tbody>
```

data object represent following data as any[]

```
companyName: "Innovasic, Inc."
done: "0"
notImpacted: "0"
notificationDate: "2009-11-12"
offilneURL: "https://source.z2data.com/2019/1/13/8/55/47/351/662203977/21527_SPCN.PDF"
onlineURL: "N/A"
pending: "3"
reportDate: "2020-05-07"
revisionID: "272299243"
teamName: "MFG"
totalCount: 79
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this? this.contentBody = data.filter(item =>item.totalCount !== data[0].totalCount);

Comment: thanks for reply i do it but all data and records does not display

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I misread your question. I think you need to filter your headerCols.  this.headerCols = Object.keys(data[0]).filter(x => x !== 'totalCount');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it solved by change my code above to

```
this.headerCols = Object.keys(data[0]).filter(x => x !== 'totalCount');
```